# I want to stream a webcam feed using socket programming in Python

Tags: python, sockets, camera, streaming, pygame

This is my code:

#### server.py:

```
#The server receives the data

import socket
from PIL import Image
import pygame,sys
import pygame.camera
from pygame.locals import *
import time

host = "localhost"
port = 1890
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((host,port))
s.listen(1)
conn, addr = s.accept()
print "connected by",addr

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640,480))

while 1:
        data = conn.recv(921637)
        image = pygame.image.fromstring(data,(640,480),"RGB")
        screen.blit(image,(0,0))
        pygame.display.update()
        if not image: 
               break;
        conn.send(data)
conn.close()
```

#### client.py

```
#The client sends the data

import socket
from PIL import Image
import pygame,sys
import pygame.camera
from pygame.locals import *
import time

host = "localhost"
port = 1890
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((host, port))


pygame.init()
pygame.camera.init()
cam = pygame.camera.Camera("/dev/video0",(640,480))
cam.start()

while 1:
        image = cam.get_image()
        data = pygame.image.tostring(image,"RGB")
        s.sendall(data)     

s.close()
print "recieved", repr(data)
```

Just to test, I tried the following code and it's working fine, but the above does not...

Working code when implemeted without sockets: camcapture.py

```
import sys
import time
import pygame
import pygame.camera
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()
pygame.camera.init()
cam = pygame.camera.Camera("/dev/video0",(640,480))
cam.start()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640,480))

while 1:
        image = cam.get_image()
        data = pygame.image.tostring(image,"RGB")
        img = pygame.image.fromstring(data,(640,480),"RGB")
        screen.blit(img,(0,0))
        pygame.display.update()
```

The error is:

```
image = pygame.image.fromstring(data,(640,480),"RGB")
ValueError: String length does not equal format and resolution size
```

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: It seems your camera's resolution is not 640x480, try using `image.get_size()` instead of `(640,480)`.

Comment: were do i exactly put it? in server.py? i dont understand, if the data is the same then how can the size vary between the two programs?

Comment: I just meant that you should consider sending the size of your camera's image's resolution, before sending your image.. This might work.

Answer (score 10):

The problem is not the camera.

The problem is that you send a very large string over the socket and you incorrectly assume that you can read the entire string at once with `conn.recv(921637)`.

You'll have to call `recv` multiple times to receive all over your data. Try printing the length of `data` you send in `client.py` and print the length of `data` in `server.py` before calling `pygame.image.fromstring` and you'll see.

There are several ways to solve this:

- make a new connection for each image you send
- send the size of your data so the server knows how much data to read
- use some kind of end marker

---

Here's a simple example:

#### sender:

```
import socket
import pygame
import time

host = "localhost"
port = 1890
pygame.init()
image = pygame.surface.Surface((640, 480))
i=0
j=0
while 1:
    image.fill((i,j,0))
    i+=10
    j+=5
    if i >= 255: i = 0
    if j >= 255: j = 0
    data = pygame.image.tostring(image,"RGB")
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect((host, port))
    s.sendall(data)
    s.close()
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

#### receiver:

```
import socket
import pygame

host="localhost"
port=1890

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640,480))

while 1:
    s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.bind((host,port))
    s.listen(1)
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    message = []
    while True:
        d = conn.recv(1024*1024)
        if not d: break
        else: message.append(d)
    data = ''.join(message)
    image = pygame.image.fromstring(data,(640,480),"RGB")
    screen.blit(image,(0,0))
    pygame.display.update()
```