# Real-time streaming using Python

Tags: python, streaming, real-time, rtsp, live-streaming

I wish to develop a video encoder system using Raspberry Pi and I am using Python in order to do the encoding. Now I have to push this encoded video to a remote server live so that the server serves the video to the connected clients live. I have searched for a solution but didn't get a proper way to implement the same.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with sockets. Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15003778/i-want-to-stream-a-webcam-feed-using-socket-programming-in-python) question. The top answer has pretty good client/server code that might suit your needs.